# How is the idea of an orthogonal matrix equivalent to $\lambda_{ij}$?

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotation

In my classical dynamics class, my professor showed how a vector under rotational coordinate transformation behaves. During the lecture, he used $\sum R_{ij} \mathbf{V_j} = \mathbf V_i'$ where $\mathbf{V}$ is the original vector and $\mathbf V'$ is the vector after the transformation. According to the lecture, $R_{ij}$ is any orthogonal matrix. While I am reading my textbook, I see the book defined $\lambda_{ij}=\cos(\mathbf v_i,\mathbf v_j)$ i.e. the cosine of the angle between the chosen axis. (I will upload a picture if my definition is not clear enough)

Everything the book derived is the same as my professor did, except the $R_{ij}$ becomes  $\lambda_{ij}$. So my question is, I certainly know that they are equivalent, but how? Can someone provide me a bit more insight on how the components(?) of the affine transformation matrix is related to the $\lambda_{ij}$?

( I kind of have a feeling that they are related in exactly the way it is described, but I don't seem to be understanding it thoroughly, I appreciate any insight and comments. Thank you)

Comment: Regarding the last question. Have a look at axial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) and polar vectors . These two types of vector quantities are transformed differently by reflections, this is VERY important in atomic and solid-state Physics, when working out the selection rules. e.g. polar vectors are the electric dipoles, electric field etc. Axial vectors are magnetic dipoles, magnetic fields etc.

Comment: Have you tried to connect those on an x-y plane?